# Magento 2 Mini Cart is not working with production version

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

I have developed custom theme on the top of local installation of https://github.com/magento/magento2 version and it works fine. I installed magento production version (2.0.2) https://www.magentocommerce.com/download on my server and installed my theme. But the issue is minicart is not collapsing in browser console there is an error which responsible for this

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "css: function (){return { empty:!!getCartParam('summary_count') == false} }"
Message: getCartParam is not defined
```

due to this error other knockoutjs scripts also not working which are below to above line . could you please help me to resolve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue , git version of magento has a different knockoutjs scripts than production version.In git version it use `getCartParam()` function to retrieve/bind data but in magento 2.0.2 production version is using `cart()` function instead of getCartParam so I just copied minicart files from production version core and edited it . So it worked. I'm posting this if this is help to some one else

Comment: i am using production version still getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Remove `pub/static/frontend/{theme_vendor}` folder
- Remove `var/cache` and `var/view_preprocessed` folders

Go to root (by SSH) and execute:

- php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

This should be enough if not, you should take a look at your theme code.

Comment: I tried this but not worked still has the issue